# Quick string replace mod_rewrite question

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

all i want do is change my querystring from this

result/?q=Southview+Guesthouse
to this:
result/?q=Southview-Guesthouse.

I've done similar stuff with PHP but never mod_rewrite, has anyone got any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're only talking about two alphabetic words separated by a plus, this should work (I have tested it and it is working for me):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "q=([a-z]+)\+([a-z]+)(&|$)" [NC]
RewriteRule result/$ result/?q=%1-%2 [L,R]
```

`%N` (where `N` is 0-9) in a `RewriteRule` pattern refers to a backreference in a `RewriteCond`.